# Using enumerate method not able to delete last item in list (python3)

Tags: python, list, enumerate

I am trying to iterate the list and delete the last element based on the condition. But I am getting errors.

```
x = [0,2,1]
for y, v in enumerate(x):
  if v is 1:  
    del x[y]

print(x)
```

output:

```
[0,2,1]
```

Comment: Iterating over a list and manipulating it at the same type is typically a one way road to unintended consequences such as this.

Comment: You can just use `x.remove(1)`.

Comment: What, **exactly** are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: note, `if v is 1` is wrong

Comment: also note, your code actually results in `[0, 2, 1]` but it is still probably buggy

Answer (score 1):

It's not recommended to iterate into a list changing its elements, since you are removing the element by value you can do like this:

```
x = [0, 2, 1]
for i in range(x.count(1)):
    x.remove(1)

print(x)
```

Output

```
[0, 2]
```

Comment: this is a pretty inefficient approach though, funamentally polynomial time, you can do it in linear time trivially

Comment: i don't think time efficiency is a variable in this question btw, but nice point

Comment: sure, but you should avoid writing inefficient code when there is an idiomatic, trivial, efficient alternative. e.g. `x = [item for item in x if item != 0]`

Comment: when the code efficiency isn't a deal, since the OP is a beginner clearly, list comprehension isn't the best approach

Comment: You can just write the equivalent for-loop, which is perfectly pythonic and idiomatic. Absolutely, a beginner should not be shown unidiomatic, unnecessarily inefficient approaches, especially not if you don't point that out.